# How to set private environment variables for Cypress tests?

Tags: environment-variables, cypress

I have a private test api key that I want to use in my Cypress tests.

All the env vars are in the `.env` file but I want to use a different .env file for my Cypress tests. Something like `cypress.env`. Is this possible?

I don't want to set Cypress env vars... I want to set system env vars for my cypress tests.

```
// .env
SECRET_KEY="foo"

// .cypress.env
SECRET_KEY="bar"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got [Option #2: cypress.env.json](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-2-cypressenvjson) which is automatically picked up by the runner

> You can create your own **cypress.env.json** file that Cypress will automatically check. Values in here will overwrite conflicting environment variables in your Cypress configuration.
>
> ```js
> {
>   "host": "veronica.dev.local",
>   "api_server": "http://localhost:8888/api/v1/"
> }
> ```